# displaying a changing sorted array inside a textbox in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, textbox

I want to display an array onto a textbox in C# in the order of lowest to highest, but the numbers in the array are constantly changing, so it has to rearrange itself.

Comment: Interesting. What is the use case of this? Because winforms need to keep the array in memory in order to display. If it is ever changing, your memory usage will go sky high.

Comment: Ideas like this almost never work out.  Your sorting will happen faster than windows can draw the changes and much much faster than the eye can perceive.  Likely an XY problem

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a class and have a `Add` method which adds your object at right position and rises an event, so you can update your textbox using this event handler each time asynchronously.
Can you explain more? Why you need this? You may find better ways to reach your goal.